# Beginner Python query - selecting items in a JSON list

Tags: python, json

I have a list of JSON twitter files that I read into a list in Python like so:

```
data5=[]
with codecs.open('twitFile_5.txt','rU') as file5:
    for line in file5:
       data5.append(json.loads(line))
```

I can select "text" for example to give me a selected tweet

```
data5[1]["text"]
```

However I don't know how to

1) just make a list of all the "text" items

2) search that "text" list and count the number of times a list of phrases is mentioned in the text e.g. ['apple', 'orange fruit', 'bunch of bananas'].

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) could solve these:

For example:

```
texts = map(lambda x: x['text'], data5)
```

and:

```
texts = ['apple test', 'test orange fruit']

init = { 'apple': 0, 'orange fruit': 0, 'bunch of bananas': 0 }

def aggregate(agg,x):
  for k in agg:
    if k in x:
      agg[k] += 1
  return agg

counts = reduce(aggregate, texts, init)
```

**Edit**

Per comment:

```
values = [
    {'text': 'apple test', 'user': 'A'},
    {'text': 'test orange fruit', 'user': 'B'}
  ]

init = { 'apple': [], 'orange fruit': [], 'bunch of bananas': [] }

def aggregate(agg,x):
  for k in agg:
    if k in x['text']:
      agg[k].append(x)
  return agg

counts = reduce(aggregate, values, init)
```

Comment: Thanks! I should probably just ask a new question - but how about if I want to also return other list details for each of the searched for tweets, such as "user" for example?

Comment: @Betty Do you mean like instead of `x['text']`? You could return any arbitrary object. The simplest would be a tuple so something like `(x['text'],x['user'])` and that might work well for a handful of fields. A tuple is basically just a fixed size list so you access things by index. For something more robust, you would probably want to define a `class` and construct and return an instance.

Comment: What's there is perfect for now.  What I was thinking was for every time "apple" is found returning more details such as the user, but perhaps it would make more sense to use a SQL database for that kind of querying.

Comment: @Betty I updated the answer. Rather than an integer counter, you can use a list. The length of the list then would be the "count", but this way you can get the matched values as well.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! One more thing as this is great stuff to learn...This returns everything in my list relating to the search term.  Is there any way to just return certain fields like "user" or "date_created"?

Comment: @Betty So this would return everything that made it as far as the `init` list. If you wanted to filter further from there, you would change the `.append(x)` and replace the `x` with some new data structure (dict, tuple, class instance etc.) containing the subset of `x` that you want.

Comment: Ok, I get that, great, thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

1) Use a list comprehension

```
texts = [d["text"] for d in data5]
```

2) List comprehension again

```
count = len([t for t in texts if 'apple' in t])
```

I'm interpreting your post to mean you want to count the number of texts that mention "apple."  If you want to count the number of times "apple" occurs you can use

```
count = sum([t.count('apple') for t in texts])
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  How about if I want to also return other list details for each of the searched for tweets, such as "user" for example.